# Cannot find symbol variable bound_observable

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using data binding in my android app, I am implementing two-way data binding. 
I created a a custom attribute using the annotation @BindingAdapter like this,

```
 @BindingAdapter({"app:bindingText"})
public static void bindEditText(EditText view, final BindableString bindableString) {

    Pair<BindableString, SimpleTextWatcher> pair = (Pair) view.getTag(R.id.bound_observable);
    if (pair == null || pair.first != bindableString) {
        if (pair != null) {
            view.removeTextChangedListener(pair.second);
        }
        SimpleTextWatcher watcher = new SimpleTextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(String newValue) {
                bindableString.set(newValue);
            }
        };
        view.setTag(R.id.bound_observable, new Pair<>(bindableString, watcher));
        view.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }
    String newValue = bindableString.get();
    if (!view.getText().toString().equals(newValue)) {
        view.setText(newValue);
    }
}
```

it says cannot find symbol variable bound_observable, I am kind of new to data binding, so help me.

Comment: Post your XML layout code that shows `bound_observable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared `R.id.bound_observable` in resources?

```
<resources>
    <item name="R.id.bound_observable" type="id" />
</resources>
```

Any way, new version of DataBinding library offers own two-way binding like this

```
android:text="@={viewModel.bindableString}"
```